# Конструктор по-умолчанию для константного класса

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, класс

Почему эта программа не компилируется?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() = default;
    int x;
};

int main() {
    const A a;
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

А вот эта компилируется?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A();
    int x;
};

A::A() = default;

int main() {
    const A a;
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

И эта тоже работает:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() = default;
    int x;
};

int main() {
    const A a{};
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

Ошибка компиляции:

> error: uninitialized 'const a'

Comment: в любом случае во всех трех кейсах у вас UB так как читаете неинициализированное поле

Comment: @Ildar UB тут нет ни в одном, а поле остается неинициализированным только в первом, но компилятор этого гарантировано не разрешает

Comment: @user7860670 точно в третьем по умолчанию нулем закидывает конструктор, но во втором точно неинициализированно же, и разве чтение из неинициализированных полей не считается UB?

Comment: @Ildar Нет, во втором они инициализируется сгенерированным конструктором по-умолчанию.

Comment: @user7860670 Похоже все-таки нет: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fWbaz5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае `A() = default;` не производит инициализацию `x`. Класс остается тривиально инициализируемым. `static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<A>);`

Во втором сначала объявляется *пользовательский* конструктор по-умолчанию `A();`, который затем генерируется и инициализирует `x`. Класс уже не будет тривильно инициализируемым `static_assert(not std::is_trivially_constructible_v<A>);`

В третьем неинициализированные поля инициализируются на месте `const A a{};` за счет использования синтаксиса direct list initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Тривиальность конструктора тут не при чем. Если добавить к классу поле с нетривиальным конструктором (например`std::string`), то `std::is_trivially_constructible` будет в любом случае возвращать `false`, а поведение не изменится.

---

У конструктора по умолчанию, автоматически сгенерированного компилятором (не наш случай), **или** объявленного как `=default` **внутри тела класса** (наш случай) есть особое свойство, которое нельзя повторить в самодельном конструкторе.

Поведение такого конструктора зависит от того, были ли использованы скобки `()` или `{}` при его вызове (value initialization), или нет (default initialization):

- Если скобок нет, то он ведет себя как обычно.
- Если скобки есть, то поля, которые иначе остались бы неинициализированными, зануляются (value initialization).

А если конструктор объявлен как `=default` **снаружи** тела класса, то у него такого специального поведения не будет. Насколько я знаю, он ничем не будет отличаться от пустого конструктора (`{}` вместо `=default`).

---

Так вот. В первом случае сработала защита от дурака, про которую я раньше не слышал. (В духе запрета на объявления вроде `const int x;` без инициализатора.)

> [`[dcl.init]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7)
> ...
> A class type `T` is *const-default-constructible* if
> default-initialization of `T` would invoke a user-provided constructor
> of `T` (not inherited from a base class) or if
>
> (7.4) —
> each direct ... non-static data member `M` of `T` has a default member initializer or, if `M` is of class type `X` (or array
> thereof), `X` is const-default-constructible,
> ...
> If a program calls for the default-initialization of an object of a
> const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a const-default-constructible class
> type or array thereof.

То есть ошибку вызывает default-инициализация (то есть без использования скобок `()` или `{}`, с ними была бы value-инициализация) константного экземпляра класса, у которого конструктор по умолчанию не user-provided (то есть сгенерирован компилятором автоматически, или отмечен как `=default` внутри тела класса), если у класса есть поля, котороые при таком раскладе остались бы неинициализированными.

---

В третьем случае `x` инициализируется нулем, и параграф выше не применяется (и то и другое - потому что для инициализации используются скобки).

---

Во втором случае `x` остается неинициализированным, но никакой защиты от этого нет.

Можно догадаться почему:

- Во-первых, в общем случае сложно определить, присваивает ли конструктор какое-то значение полю или нет.
- Во-вторых, определение конструктора могло быть спрятано в отдельную единицу трансляции, и хотя в здесь этого сделано не было, компилятор все равно не смотрит в тело конструктора. Предположительно для того, чтобы перемещение его в отдельную единицу трансляции не меняло поведение кода.